# ios custom label not support font family only support Lucida Grande?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, xcode4.5

i'm using Lucida Grande font family it works fine.

```
FontLabel *label4 = [[FontLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6, 250, 50)];
        ZMutableAttributedString *str = [[ZMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:cmd_string
                                                                              attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                                          [[FontManager sharedManager] zFontWithName:@"Lucida Grande" pointSize:12],
                                                                                          ZFontAttributeName,
                                                                                          nil]];
        label4.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [str addAttribute:ZFontAttributeName value:[[FontManager sharedManager] zFontWithName:@"Lucida Grande" pointSize:12] range:NSMakeRange(0, name_length)];
        [str addAttribute:ZForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:241/255.0f green:73.0/255.0f blue:2.0/255.0f alpha:1.0]range:NSMakeRange(0, name_length)];
        [str addAttribute:ZForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0f green:121.0/255.0f blue:98.0/255.0f alpha:1.0]range:NSMakeRange(name_length, cmd_str_len-name_length)];
        label4.zAttributedText = str;
        label4.numberOfLines=0;
        [label4 sizeToFit];
```

i'm using Helvetica-Bold font family it not working app crahing, please help me.

```
FontLabel *label4 = [[FontLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6, 250, 50)];
        ZMutableAttributedString *str = [[ZMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:cmd_string
                                                                              attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                                          [[FontManager sharedManager] zFontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" pointSize:12],
                                                                                          ZFontAttributeName,
                                                                                          nil]];
        label4.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [str addAttribute:ZFontAttributeName value:[[FontManager sharedManager] zFontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" pointSize:12] range:NSMakeRange(0, name_length)];
        [str addAttribute:ZForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:241/255.0f green:73.0/255.0f blue:2.0/255.0f alpha:1.0]range:NSMakeRange(0, name_length)];
        [str addAttribute:ZForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0f green:121.0/255.0f blue:98.0/255.0f alpha:1.0]range:NSMakeRange(name_length, cmd_str_len-name_length)];
        label4.zAttributedText = str;
        label4.numberOfLines=0;
        [label4 sizeToFit];
```

Comment: What's the error and stack trace when the app crashes?

Comment: thread error coming, the thread showing FontLabel supporting file.

Comment: Can you show us method definition for `zFontWithName`

Comment: have you installed Helvetica-Bold in your system

Answer (score 1):

Lucinda Grande is not available in iOS, only on Mac OS X.